# Saving two RDDs in parallel

Tags: scala, apache-spark

accessLogs.saveAsTextFile(outputDirectory1)

accessList.saveAsTextFile(outputDirectory2)

How to save both the RDD in parallel rather than in series?

Comment: do you need separate or you want to have one single file ?

Comment: If I may ask what's the reason of doing that ? What's to gain ?

Answer (score 3):

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val rdds = Seq(accessLogs, accessLists)
val dirs = Seq("outputDirectory1", "outputDirectory2")

import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val future = Future.sequence(
  for ((rdd, dir) <- rdds zip dirs) yield Future(rdd.saveAsTextFile(dir))
)
//Await.ready(future, Duration.Inf) //to wait for rdds to be saved...
```

Note that despite the name, the method `sequence` on the `Future` companion object used above will execute the `Futures` resulting from the for-comprehension in parallel and not sequentially. This `sequence` method is essentially an applicative functor `sequence`.

Answer (score 1):

You can save them in threads.

```
  new Thread() {
      override def run(): Unit = {
accessLogs.saveAsTextFile(outputDirectory1) 
      }
    }.start()

  new Thread() {
      override def run(): Unit = {
accessList.saveAsTextFile(outputDirectory2)
      }
    }.start()
```

`saveAsTextFile` doesn't return anything, so I am not sure why are you setting the return value.

Comment: Thank you my bad there is no return value. Its just persisting different rdds to different files .